# Crear ID única con comprobación en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

En mi aplicación web se pueden crear "*páginas*" que serán identificadas con una **cadena de texto aleatoria**, que se usará para acceder a la página de este modo: `ejemplo.com/xxxxxx`

Lo que necesito es saber la mejor forma de crear estas cadenas (que serán almacenadas en la **base de datos** junto a sus respectivos datos) y que sean **únicas** el 100% de las veces.

¿Debería hacer un `SELECT` cada vez que se crea un enlace para **verificar si existe**?

```
function generarID($longitud = 6) {
    $caracteres = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $longCaracteres = strlen($caracteres);
    $idAleatoria = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $longitud; $i++) {
        $idAleatoria .= $caracteres[rand(0, $longCaracteres - 1)];
    }
    return $idAleatoria;
}
```

Con la mejor verificación, me refiero a la más rápida y que menos recursos consuma. Actualmente tengo 300 enlaces por día, y lo único que hago es dejar que MySQL muestre el error si resulta que está duplicado, ya que la columna cuenta con el atributo de `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a la generación del identificador único por página que estás buscando, hay dos posibilidades:

- Generarlo con PHP mediante la función [*uniqid()*](http://php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php)
- Generarlo en el servidor MySQL con el método [*UUID()*](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?sqlfun=UUID)

Ámbas opciones generan un identificador que es compatible con las direcciones URL, es decir, lo vas a poder usar para direccionar a las páginas.

Hay que tener en cuenta que si bien las posibilidades de que te devuelvan dos identificadores iguales(llamado colisión) es muy baja, esta no deja de existir.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, en el primer caso te sigue quedando pendiente hacer la verificación. Como decís que en este momento estás generando unos 300 uid por día, la consulta a la BBDD antes de insertar el nuevo registro es viable. Aunque, si la cantidad de páginas generadas crece mucho, vas a encontrarte teniendo que consultar varias veces hasta conseguir uno que no esté repetido.

En el segundo caso, al generar MySQL el UUID y al estar la columna restringida como UNIQUE el mismo motor de BBDD va generar otro automáticamente para evitar la colisión. Con esta opción, luego de insertar el registro, vas a tener que recuperarlo para conocer el identificador generado.

Te recomendaría, a menos que tengas razones para inclinarte por la primera, que dejes en manos de la BBDD la creación del identificador y lo recuperes luego de insertado el registro.